# Windows 10 0xc0000001 error after Using Gparted

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, gparted

I have a dual boot system (Fedora + Windows 10), I wanted to add some extra space to the windows side using Gparted but when i launch windows 10 i got into the automatic repair bootloop so i disabled automatic repair, Now i have a 0xc0000001 error code

What i tried :

1. Fixing the MBR from the command prompt
2. Rebuild BCD

   I can backup the old BCD but when trying to remove the read-only attribute i get no file found so i can't replace it
3. CHKDSK return no corrupt file to fix
4. sfc /scannow no error found

I have important files on my pc so reinstalling windows isn't an option :/

I ended up reinstalling windows and fedora before even @cybernard posted his answer and by tinkering a little bit here and there i started to understand how windows booting process works, and i have the logical sensation that his reply would work, I am leaving this tip behind this post in which is a recommendation for his solution if you find yourself in the same situation give it a try, cheers

Comment: I have never in over 20 years of using Windows been able to recover from the error you describe. You should be able to extract the most important information but ultimately you will have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound My bad, thanks for your input if there are no other choice at least i will have the peace of mind that nothing nothing can be done

Comment: Best choice: restore from the disk image you made before changing disk partitions. Otherwise,  make an image now, because each attempt to fix the issue makes it harder, or impossible, to recover data; salvage as much of the Windows installation as possible (from the image, preferably), then reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

0xc0000001 error code is a vital piece of the Operating System not found.

Abandoning the Automatic Repair means you need to see if you have a backup and / or can recover the data you need by booting with a USB Key.

Then you need to reinstall Windows. This is the only choice I see given your description.

Answer (score 0):

Windows error code 0xc0000001 means that you can't boot the system,
often due to corrupt or missing system files.

Gparted works better on Linux disks than on Windows disks. It sometimes
fails on resizing Windows partitions, in effect making the disk
unbootable. Resizing a Windows disk is better done when booting Windows
and from inside Windows itself,
but moving Windows partitions has to be done using Gparted or others
because Windows doesn't do that.

A faint hope for fixing the problem is to
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
using a Windows boot media or a recovery disk.

To save your data, you could insert the disk in another computer,
or in an external enclosure, and hope that the Windows partition
is still readable.

If you have a disk-image backup of the disk, the best solution is
to restore it (but I suppose you don't). In the future, take really
good backups before doing any partition editing of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

You need a boot CD/DVD/USB with bootable copy of windows.  I usually use microsoft media creation tool.

Boot from it.

Shift F10  (should get you a ms-dos like command prompt, maybe Shift f8)

I get this sometimes, and usually using

```
diskpart
```

Select the system volume, one without an existing drive letter.  (System Reserved type).

```
select vol 0  (or whatever # it is for you)
assign letter=h
exit
```

Then goto your h drive

```
h:
```

Then navigate to the BCD file and rename or delete it.  It could be hidden, if that is the case.

```
attrib -h -r -s h:\boot\bcd
ren bcd bcd.bad
```

Then build a new one

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

If you don't delete or rename the old one you will likely get access denied.
Sometimes it will say 0 installations of windows found if the existing BCD is damaged.

Comment: This doesn't work for UEFI booting